# Rails 4.2 ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration is called 4 times on a refresh / restart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

Running an app using 4.2beta2 ( upgraded from Rails 3.2) under nginx/passenger in dev mode, against a mysql 5.5 server using rbenv/mri 2.1.3

And I'm seeing this in the log:

```
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.9ms)  SELECT `schema_migrations`.* FROM `schema_migrations`
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `schema_migrations`.* FROM `schema_migrations`
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (2.7ms)  SELECT `schema_migrations`.* FROM `schema_migrations`
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.7ms)  SELECT `schema_migrations`.* FROM `schema_migrations`
```

Any one has any idea why this might be called 4 times? Not a terrible hit on the server mind you, just wondering if I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok for anyone else looking for a solution, mine turned to be a combination of looking into how rails's  ModelName.exists? works, figuring our how configatron  gem works and fixing configatron initializer

The bottom line ModelName.exists? wasn't caches  and was called 4 times from my code. Fixed to only be called once.